# using uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb() instead of uwsgi.websocket_recv() causes uwsgi to terminate connection after 30 seconds

Tags: python, websocket, uwsgi

I am trying to implement a simple websockets application in pure Python + uWSGI.

Initially I wrote it just using uwsgi.websocket_recv() to get messages from the client. This worked just fine, however as I want my application to be able to handle multiple clients concurrently and exchange messages between them, so I changed this to use uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb() which is the non-blocking variant.

I noticed that when using uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb() instead of uwsgi.websocket_recv(), the connection to the server will be terminated 30 seconds after the client connects, and uwsgi will spit out the following error in the console:

[uwsgi-websocket] "GET /" (192.168.1.16) no PONG received in 3 seconds !!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/www/wsgi-websocket-2.py", line 14, in application
    makesock(env, start_response)
  File "/home/www/wsgi-websocket-2.py", line 32, in makesock
    msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb()
IEError: unable to receive websocket message

This occurs even when the client is actively exchanging messages with the server. No matter how active the connection is, it dies 30 seconds after connecting every time. This does not happen when I use uwsgi.websocket_recv().

Any clues as to why this is happening and how I can mitigate it to keep the connection open indefinitely?

Thanks

Comment: I did some digging around some code examples and noticed a lot of people using `uwsgi.connection_fd()` and `gevent.select.select()`. 

I ended up adding the following code right after calling `uwsgi.websocket_handshake()`:

`websocket_fd = uwsgi.connection_fd()`

and I added the following to the beginning of my while loop:

`gevent.select.select([websocket_fd], [], [], 0.0)`

NOTE: This requires `from gevent import select`

I can't say I really understand what this does, but whatever it is, it fixes my problem. Maybe someone can explain why this is necessary in layman's terms?

Comment: Can someone explain why I need `gevent.select.select([websocket_fd], [], [], 0.0)` in the beginning of my while loop to keep the connection from dying when using `uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb()` ? I'd greatly appreciate it. I fixed my problem by adding this line to my while loop, but I would like to understand what it does and why it is necessary to keep the connection open longer than 30 seconds

Comment: Is this still of interest? My knowledge of the topic is not much deeper than yours, but I am dealing with a similar problem. If you show something of your code, I could try to write something like an answer.

Comment: @JosefScript I am facing the same issue. If you could give an explanation that would be great!